# Additional column showing matching values within the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table with a ton of columns and rows. What I'm trying to do in my query statement is to create a new column that will show any additional rows that share the same attribute as that individual row.

Example - here is the original table

| Name | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Jake | GroupA |
| Mike | GroupB |
| Sandy | GroupC |
| John | GroupD |
| Silvia | GroupA |
| Matt | GroupA |

This is what im trying to output in oracle via my query

| Name | Group | Associated People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | GroupA | Matt, Silvia |
| Mike | GroupB | John |
| Sandy | GroupC | NULL |
| John | GroupB | Mike |
| Silvia | GroupA | Jake, Matt |
| Matt | GroupA | Jake, Silvia |

my query is much larger than this with much more columns and rows but this is the gist of what im trying to do - There is actually over 2 million rows of data with 50 columns in the actual table I'm querying from that the data changes row numbers every couple hours and I would need to match multiple columns. Thanks

Here is a redaction/snip of the actual query but im getting a "not in group expression" error after adding the subquery

```
SELECT  ncp.host AS Host,
            substr(ncp.host,1,4) AS IP
            ncp.node_name AS Node_Name,
            substr(ncp.device,6) AS technology,
            ncp.grouping,
            (SELECT listagg(ncp1.node_name,',') within group(ORDER BY ncp1.node_name) FROM node.plan ncp1 WHERE ncp1.host_name = ncp.host_name
 AND ncp1.serving_group = ncp.serving_group
 AND ncp1.node_name != ncp.node_name) AS Sibling_Nodes
FROM node.plan ncp
LEFT JOIN node_sum.sum ncs ON ncp.site_id = ncs.site_id
WHERE ncp.flag = 'N'
GROUP BY ncp.host,
     ncp.node_name,
     ncp.device,
     ncp.grouping
```

Comment: why have Silvia and Matt no associated people?

Comment: Thanks MT0, I will try this. There is however over 2 million rows of data with 50 columns in the actual table I'm querying from that the data changes row numbers every couple hours and I would need to match multiple columns. will this still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` and `LISTAGG` analytic functions combined with `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT name,
       group_name,
       CASE rn
       WHEN 1
       THEN LISTAGG(CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN name END, ',')
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn)
              OVER (PARTITION BY group_name)
       END AS associated_people
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         group_name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Group_name) AS
SELECT 'Jake',   'GroupA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike',   'GroupB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sandy',  'GroupC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',   'GroupB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Silvia', 'GroupA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Matt',   'GroupA' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| NAME | GROUP_NAME | ASSOCIATED_PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | GroupA | Matt,Silvia |
| Matt | GroupA | *null* |
| Silvia | GroupA | *null* |
| John | GroupB | Mike |
| Mike | GroupB | *null* |
| Sandy | GroupC | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/scri7WcN)

Comment: Yes, that seems closer to what OP seems to ask for than what I proposed.

Comment: Thanks MT0, I will try this. There is however over 2 million rows of data with 50 columns in the actual table I'm querying from that the data changes row numbers every couple hours and I would need to match multiple columns. will this still work?

Comment: @GMB The OP has changed their expected output and it looks like your solution is what they expect.

Comment: Ah... Life is unpredictable... Let me undelete, then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select listagg(t1.name, ', ') within group(order by t1.name)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.group = t.group and t1.name != t.name
    ) associated_people
from mytable t
```

This lists all other people that belong to the same group:

| NAME | GRP | ASSOCIATED_PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | GroupA | Matt, Silvia |
| Mike | GroupB | John |
| Sandy | GroupC | *null* |
| John | GroupB | Mike |
| Silvia | GroupA | Jake, Matt |
| Matt | GroupA | Jake, Silvia |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tQZQ01Td)

Comment: that still wouldn't explain how Silvia has NULL associated friends

Comment: nbk: yes. I would suspect that was a typo in OP's expected results. Let's see.

Comment: so you should wait till he responds to the comment, as of now the query doesn't produce the wanted result

Comment: @nbk It may be a typo in the input data rather than the output data.

Comment: thanks GMB, tried this but getting a "not a group by expression". what part if any should i put in my group by statement?

Comment: @cpljp: there is no group by clause in the query I provided. Please run it as it is.

Comment: (select listagg(ncp1.node_name,',') within group(order by ncp1.node_name) from node.plan ncp1 where ncp1.host_name = ncp.host_name and ncp1.serving_group = ncp.serving_group and ncp1.node_name != ncp.node_name) as Sibling_Nodes this is what i tried and i get that error. my overall query has a group by. This is my actual subquery; I didn't want to include more in my example due to sensitive information

Comment: The subquery should not have a group by clause @cpljp, as shown in my query.

Comment: I took out the group by, same issue. the overal query is telling me not a group by expression

Comment: We don’t know anything about the *overall query*, which is not mentioned in your question, so it’s hard to help here…

Comment: I know I'm sorry, the overall query is a bit proprietary and log as far as the outputs, let me see if I can redact part of the query and give you the actual one. thanks

Comment: Yes. That’s worth another question probably @cpljp.

Comment: @GMB added my shortened and redacted actual query

Answer (score 1):

Try it like here:

```sql
WITH    --  Sample data
    tbl (A_NAME, A_GROUP) AS
        (
            Select 'Jake', 'GroupA' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Mike', 'GroupB' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Sandy', 'GroupC' From Dual Union All
            Select 'John', 'GroupD' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Silvia', 'GroupA' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Matt', 'GroupA' From Dual 
        )

M a i n   S Q L:
Select  A_NAME, A_GROUP, 
        RTRIM(REPLACE( LISTAGG(A_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By A_NAME) OVER(Partition By A_GROUP) || ', ', A_NAME || ', ', '' ), ', ') "ASSOCIATED_PEOPLE"
From    tbl

R e s u l t :
A_NAME A_GROUP ASSOCIATED_PEOPLE 
------ ------- ------------------
Jake   GroupA  Matt, Silvia     
Matt   GroupA  Jake, Silvia     
Silvia GroupA  Jake, Matt       
Mike   GroupB                    
Sandy  GroupC                    
John   GroupD
```

`LISTAGG` creates a list of names. `REPLACE` removes a name in current row from the list. `RTRIM` removes the trailing comma.

---

**Addition**:

I tried to create sample data to match your added SQL and implement the same principle. If I got the data right you don't need the `GROUP BY` clause. You could, probably, do the job by adjusting the `PARTITION BY` clause of the `LISTAGG` analytic function.

Here is my guess of sample data, your a bit changed SQL and the result:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    d a t a
    node_plan (SITE_ID, HOST, DEVICE, NODE_NAME, SERVING_GROUP, GROUPING, FLAG) AS
        (
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST1 TECHNOLOGY A',  'Jake',     'GroupA', 'Y', 'N' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST2 TECHNOLOGY B',  'Mike',     'GroupB', 'Y', 'N' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST3 TECHNOLOGY B',  'Sandy',    'GroupC', 'Y', 'N' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST4 TECHNOLOGY A',  'John',     'GroupB', 'Y', 'N' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST5 TECHNOLOGY C',  'Silvia',   'GroupA', 'Y', 'N' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '192.xxx.yyy.zzz', 'HOST6 TECHNOLOGY A',  'Matt',     'GroupA', 'Y', 'N' From Dual 
        ),
    node_sum_sum (SITE_ID, SOME_COL1, SOME_COL2) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'some data', 'some more data' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'some data', 'some more data' From Dual 
        )
--  Y o u r   S Q L  - changed a bit
SELECT  ncp.HOST "HOST",
        SubStr(ncp.HOST, 1, 4) "IP",
        ncp.NODE_NAME AS "NODE_NAME",
        SubStr(ncp.DEVICE, 6) AS "TECHNOLOGY",
        ncp.GROUPING "GROUPING",
        ncp.SERVING_GROUP "SERVING_GROUP",
        RTRIM(REPLACE( LISTAGG(ncp.NODE_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By ncp.NODE_NAME) OVER(Partition By ncp.HOST, ncp.SERVING_GROUP) || ', ', NODE_NAME || ', ', '' ), ', ') "SIBLING_NODES"
FROM 
    node_plan ncp
LEFT JOIN 
    node_sum_sum ncs ON (ncp.SITE_ID = ncs.SITE_ID)
WHERE 
    ncp.FLAG = 'N'

--  R e s u l t :
HOST             IP  NODE_NAME  TECHNOLOGY    GROUPING SERVING_GROUP SIBLING_NODES 
--------------- ---- --------- ------------- ---------- ------------ --------------------
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. Jake      TECHNOLOGY A  Y          GroupA       Matt, Silvia
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. Matt      TECHNOLOGY A  Y          GroupA       Jake, Silvia
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. Silvia    TECHNOLOGY C  Y          GroupA       Jake, Matt
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. John      TECHNOLOGY A  Y          GroupB       Mike
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. Mike      TECHNOLOGY B  Y          GroupB       John
192.xxx.yyy.zzz 192. Sandy     TECHNOLOGY B  Y          GroupC
```